# sklearn how to use saved model to predict new data

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, text-classification

I use sklearn trained a SVM text classifier, used tf-idf(TfidfVectorizer) to extract the feature.
now I need to save the model and load it to predict the text unseen. I will load the model in another file,  what confuses me is how to extract the new text tf-idf feature

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to save the model AND the tfidf transformer. You can either save them separately, or create a pipeline of the two and save the pipeline (this is the preferred option).

Example:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
import pickle

Tfidf = TfidfVectorizer()
LR = LogisticRegression()
pipe = Pipeline([("Tfidf", Tfidf), ("LR", LR)])
pipe.fit(X, y)

with open('pipe.pickle', 'wb') as picklefile:
    pickle.dump(pipe, picklefile)
```

You can then load the whole pipeline which upon `predict` will first apply the vectorizer and then pass it to the model:

```
with open('pipe.pickle', 'rb') as picklefile:
    saved_pipe = pickle.load(picklefile)

saved_pipe.predict(X_test)
```